# Vue toggle div overlay from above coming down

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Trying to make a div overlay come in from above going down. Full screen.
I have a VUE app and I am still learning about it.

I tried my best. The toggle works but somehow it does not make the overlay appear how I want it.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { divv: false }
  }
});
```

```
.divv {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.divvalpha {
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
.mydiv {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 3s;
}
```

```
  <div id="app" :class="{ 'divvalpha': divv }">
    <button
      :class="{ 'divvalpha': divv }"
      @click="divv = !divv"
    >PRESS ME
    </button>
    <div class="mydiv" :class="{ 'divvalpha': divv }">
    <p>MY TEXT DIV with FULL SCREEN OVERLAY COMING DOWN FROM TOP</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only put the toggle class `.hidden` on the overlay.  It starts enabled and will be removed when variable `showOverlay` becomes `true`:

```html
<div class="overlay" :class="{ hidden: !showOverlay }">
    <p>FULL SCREEN OVERLAY</p>
</div>
```

The `.hidden` class starts the overlay fully offscreen by setting its Y position to `-100%`:

```css
.hidden {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Once it's removed, the overlay will slide down to its default position.

Here's a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showOverlay: false
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.overlay {
  transition: 1.5s all;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showOverlay = true">
    PRESS ME
  </button>
  <div class="overlay" :class="{ hidden: !showOverlay }" @click="showOverlay = false">
    <p>MY TEXT DIV with FULL SCREEN OVERLAY COMING DOWN FROM TOP</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming you didn't want to use [Vue transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html), but that's another way to do it.